# How do I remove invalid byte sequences from ALL data submitted to Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding

I have a Rails 3.2.3 app running on Ruby 1.9.3.
I get the following error message when I try to display certain characters submitted through a back-end form

`ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string))`

How do I filter out all incompatible encoding/invalid byte sequences on ALL data submitted through the back-end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController`

This modules method should recursively iterate over all values in a hash and replace them with the value returned by the block.

```
module RecurseHash
  def recurse!(&blk)
    __recurse(self, &blk) if block_given?
  end

  private
  def __recurse(obj, &blk)
    if obj.is_a? Array
      obj = obj.map { |val| __recurse(val, &blk) }
    elsif obj.is_a? Hash
      obj.each_pair { |key, val| obj[key] = __recurse(val, &blk) }
    else
      obj = blk.call(obj)
    end
    obj
  end
end

class Hash
  include RecurseHash
end



class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :force_utf8

  def force_utf8
    params.recurse! do |val|
      val.force_encoding 'UTF-8'
    end
  end
end
```

**Example:**

```
h = {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], :four=>[6, {:a=>1, :b=>2}, 7]}

h.recurse! { |v| v * 2 }

# {:one=>2, :two=>4, :three=>[2, 4, 6, 8, 10], :four=>[12, {:a=>2, :b=>4}, 14]}
```

**Note:** If the block does not return anything, the value will be replaced with `nil`. You could use this to filter certain params.